# how to get list<map<string, dynamic> data each map key and value without identifying key

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dictionary

```
var result = [
    {
        "SN": 1,
        "HH_NAME": "MARYAN_MAXAMED_CIISE_XUSEEN",
        "HH_NO": "BOSBAR0222598",
        "TELEPHONE": 906689662
    },
    {
        "SN": 3,
        "HH_NAME": "HANI_AADAN_CABDI",
        "HH_NO": "BOSBAR0167538",
        "TELEPHONE": 905398109
    },
    {
        "SN": 4,
        "HH_NAME": "MAXAMED_AXMED_CABDILAAHI",
        "HH_NO": "BOSBAR0192870",
        "TELEPHONE": 907923390
    },
    {
        "SN": 2,
        "HH_NAME": "HIBAAQ_AADAN_CABDI",
        "HH_NO": "BOSBAR0167539",
        "TELEPHONE": 907545689
    },
    {
        "SN": 5,
        "HH_NAME": "MAXAMED_AXMED_KILWE",
        "HH_NO": "BOSBAR0168767",
        "TELEPHONE": 907329789
    }
];
Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: results.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                      Map map = results[index];
                      return Card(
                        elevation: 12,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              for (var value in map.values)
                                for (var key in map.keys)
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text(
                                      key.toString() +
                                          ' : ' +
                                          value.toString(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

I am doing here student results app, I converted csv to json data then I sent it to database. now I want to to get back and get all map data without identifying subjects or any other key.
if any one has more educated then me about this topic help me to do it.
many thanks.

Comment: what is your preferred out put?

Comment: it's duplicating data e.g "SN: 1, SN:1HH_NAME: 2,HH_NAME: Mohamed_ali_mohamed" show multiple times multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `for loop`, you can use `map` method on your `results[index]`'s entries, it will return you MapEntry of your items inside `results[index]`, then you can use its `key` and `value` to generate your listview's items. Try this:

```
Column(
    children: map.entries.map((e) => Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              e.key.toString() + ' : ' + e.value.toString(),
            ),
          ),).toList()
  ),
```